# Accessing controls made at runtime in two different forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

So I have two forms, (Form1 and Form2). Form2 asks how many rows of a particluar panel (TxtBoxPanel) need to be generated in Form1. The panel will contain three boxes, so if the user says to generate 5 rows in Form1, then there will be 5 panels each with 3 textboxes.

Form2 appears as shown in the image:
[Form2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXZ6F.png)

Below is the code in Form2:

```
Public Class Form2
Public Rows As Integer

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Ok.Click


    Rows = RowNum.Text  'Row num being box to enter no. of rows



    For index = 1 To Rows

        Dim TxtBoxPanel(index)   'Control Array

        Dim LeftBox(index) 'Control Array
        Dim CenterBox(index) 'Control Array
        Dim RightBox(index) 'Control Array
        Dim YAxis As Integer ' for adding TxtBoxPanel in new row

        'adding the textbox panel

        TxtBoxPanel(index) = New Panel

        Form1.MajorPanel.Controls.Add(TxtBoxPanel(index))  'referring to form1 as panel needed in form1
        TxtBoxPanel(index).Name = ("txtBoxPanel" & index)
        TxtBoxPanel(index).Size = New Size(610, 32)
        YAxis += 32
        TxtBoxPanel(index).Location = New Point(3, YAxis)

        'adding left box
        LeftBox(index) = New TextBox

        TxtBoxPanel(index).Controls.Add(LeftBox(index))
        LeftBox(index).Name = ("LeftBox" & index)



        LeftBox(index).Text = (index)
        LeftBox(index).Size = New Size(100, 20)
        LeftBox(index).Location = New Point(3, 3)

        'adding center box
        CenterBox(index) = New TextBox

        TxtBoxPanel(index).Controls.Add(CenterBox(index))
        CenterBox(index).Name = ("CenterBox" & index)
        CenterBox(index).Text = (index)
        CenterBox(index).Size = New Size(100, 20)
        CenterBox(index).Location = New Point(258, 3)

        'adding right box
        RightBox(index) = New TextBox

        TxtBoxPanel(index).Controls.Add(RightBox(index))
        RightBox(index).Name = ("RightBox" & index)
        RightBox(index).Size = New Size(100, 20)
        RightBox(index).Text = (index)
        RightBox(index).Location = New Point(495, 3)



    Next index

    Close()  'After generation of controls, Form2 closes

End Sub



End Sub
End Class
```

The boxes generate well in Form1 as shown in below image:
[Controls in Form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttWl3.png)

Now, I would like to loop through each instance of "LeftBox" so that I can print out the "Name" property of each instance when I click on the "Message" button on Form1. However, the code to generate LeftBox is located in Form2, and I'm finding it difficult to reference it in Form1.

Please note that I am generating the controls using arrays as I read somewhere they make it easier to reference the controls compared to using `Controls.Find`

So, the question is, how can I reference the controls in Form1 after they are generated at runtime?

This is how I wtried referencing the LeftBox, for example, earlier on:

```
  ' FINDING CONTROLS PROGRAMATICALLY


    For Index = 1 To Form2.Rows

        Dim LBox As TextBox

        For Each LBox In Me.Controls.Find("LeftBox" & Index, True)
            If (LBox.Name.Contains("LeftBox") = True) Then

                MsgBox(LBox.Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Testing")

            Else
                MsgBox("There's a problem", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Testing")


            End If

        Next

    Next
```

Thank you.

Comment: `Form1` has a `Controls` collection which will contain all of your controls.  Did you check that?  Show the code you used to access the controls.

Comment: Please don't put code in a comment.  Instead, _edit_ your question and add the code there.  I'm a little confused.  I thought that all of your `TxtBoxPanel` controls were on `Form1`.  The code you added seems to be looking for them in `Form2`?

Comment: Sorry about that @Chris, I just edited the question to include the code. The TxtBoxPanel does generate onto Form1, but the code for generating the panel onto form1 is on form2. That's why I thought I had to reference form2 since the code is actually there

Answer (score 0):

So finally after trying for hours, I used `List` to store each instance of the textboxes, which allowed me to reference them later. Here's the code below:

```
 Public Class Form2 
Public Rows As Integer

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OK.Click


    Rows = RowNum.Text
    Vars.Indx = Rows 'for storing the value of rows globally 


    For index = 1 To Rows

        Dim TxtBoxPanel
        Dim LeftBox
        Dim CenterBox
        Dim RightBox
        Dim YAxis As Integer  ' for adding TxtBoxPanel in new row

        'adding the textbox panel

        TxtBoxPanel = New Panel

        Form1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxPanel)
        TxtBoxPanel.Name = ("txtBoxPanel" & index)
        TxtBoxPanel.Size = New Size(610, 32)
        YAxis += 30
        TxtBoxPanel.Location = New Point(24, YAxis)

        'adding left box
        LeftBox = New TextBox

        TxtBoxPanel.Controls.Add(LeftBox)
        LeftBox.Name = ("LeftBox" & index)



        LeftBox.Text = (index)
        LeftBox.Size = New Size(100, 20)
        LeftBox.Location = New Point(3, 3)

        LeftList.Add(LeftBox)  'inserts LeftBox to list 
        'adding center box
        CenterBox = New TextBox

        TxtBoxPanel.Controls.Add(CenterBox)
        CenterBox.Name = ("CenterBox" & index)
        CenterBox.Text = index
        CenterBox.Size = New Size(100, 20)
        CenterBox.Location = New Point(258, 3)
        CenterList.Add(CenterBox)  'inserts centerbox to list
        'adding right box
        RightBox = New TextBox

        TxtBoxPanel.Controls.Add(RightBox)
        RightBox.Name = ("RightBox" & index)
        RightBox.Size = New Size(100, 20)
        RightBox.Text = index
        RightBox.Location = New Point(495, 3)

        RightList.Add(RightBox) 'adds rightbox to list

    Next index



    Close()  'After generation of controls, Form2 closes

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RowNum.TextChanged

End Sub
 End Class
```

Inorder to reference the textboxes in Form1, I had declared the List in a Module called `Vars`as shown below:

```
Module Vars
'for storing variables needed globally
'whatever needs to be "connected" to different forms, store it here

Public Indx As Integer
Public CenterList As New List(Of TextBox)   
Public RightList As New List(Of TextBox)
Public LeftList As New List(Of TextBox)

 End Module
```

Then in Form1, this is what I did:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Form2.Show()
End Sub



Private Sub Message_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Message.Click


    For index = 0 To (Vars.Indx - 1) 'loop through leftbox 

        MsgBox(LeftList(index).Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "INFO")


    Next



End Sub
End Class
```

Its working but I still wonder if this code is really efficient?